# How is the Early voltage defined?

Tags: transistors

The Early voltage is a definition rather than a real existing and measurable quantity. It can be found using the slope of the output characteristics \$I_c = f(V_{ce})\$.

However, there are two basic alternatives: **constant \$I_b\$** or **constant \$V_{be}\$**.

**Question 1**: Which of these two alternatives can be used to find the EARLY voltage?

- (a) Constant \$I_b\$,
- (b) Constant \$V_{be}\$, or
- (c) Both?

Background: Some books use definition (a), some others use (b) and some do even not specify if (a) or (b).

**Question 2**: If (c) is correct - how can we theoretically prove that both alternatives give us the same (correct) value for the Early voltage?

**EDIT**: 
For my opinion, my problem is not yet solved; therefore some further remarks:

I am aware that my question is not too relevant for circuit designers - and that is the reason I was looking for some corresponding - theoretically oriented - contributions from Universities.

Here are the results:
One lecture note from **Berkeley** Univ. defines the Early voltage VEA for **IB=const**., but in another contribution **VBE** is held constant.

Papers from **Stanford** Univ. are defining VEA for **VBE=const**.

Lecture notes from the **Columbia** Univ. define VEA also for **VBE=const**.

Even more confusing is a contribution from the **Georgia Inst. of Tech**.. Here, the Early voltage VEA is definde for **IB=const**. However, in the same paper this parameter is used in the equation y22=IC/(VEA+VCE). And - as we know, y22 is the output conductance for **VBE=const.**
Can somebody explain these contradictions?

Here are corresponding links:

- http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/sp04/handouts/lectures/Lecture22.pdf
- Georgia IT:  http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~alan/ECE3040/Lectures/Lecture20-BJT%20Small%20Signal%20Model.pdf
- http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~bbathula/courses/SSDT/lect07.pdf
- http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch8.pdf
- Stanford: https://www.coursehero.com/file/7827746/ho3BJT/

Comment: I think Ib const and Vbe const are the same condition, i.e. if one is true so is the other. The BE junction is basically a diode in FAR...

Comment: However, we should not forget that the Early effect is caused due to a shrinking of the base region (for increased Vce). This reduces Ib (for Vbe=const), because Ic is increasing (and Ie=const). Requiring Ib=const. is possible only if - at the same time - we increase Vbe correspondingly. So - are both cases really "the same condition"?

Comment: When Vbe is constant, Ie and Ib will not be constant !
It is only needed to fix one parameter, like Vbe and then determine Ic(Vce). In that case Ib or Ie actually do not matter.

Comment: Sorry - what does this mean related to my question?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch8.pdf (page 14) "In January, 1952, on my way to a Murray Hill Bell Labs internal meeting, I started to
think about how to model the collector current as a function of the collector voltage. Bored during the meeting, I put down the expression for collector current IC = β*IB.
**Differentiating with respect to VC while IB was held constant**"

Comment: G36, thank you. But this document is already referenced at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that there is a small difference due to voltage-dependent reverse leakage of the C-B junction, but it's not significant under normal conditions. To a first approximation the leakage is independent of voltage (for Vcb > a few Vt).

If the transistor is being operated at very low collector current (nA) and high collector voltage the constant base current method will give you a measurably lower value for Va.

I believe that constant Vbe is a better representation of behavior in real situations such as current mirrors.

Comment: S.Pefhany, I understand your answer as a vote in favour of my case (c), correct? On the other hand, using real numbers to prove if y22=h22 the equation y22=h22-h12*h21/h11=h22-h12*gm tells us that that there is a remarkable difference. That is the background of my question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book, Principles of Semiconductor Devices by Bart Van Zeghbroeck (link is given below for reference):

> The change of the collector current, when changing the collector-emitter voltage is primarily due to the variation of the base-collector voltage, since the base-emitter junction is forward biased and a constant base current is applied. The collector current depends on the base-collector voltage since the base-collector depletion layer width varies, which also causes the quasi-neutral width, wB', in the base to vary.
>
> [image]
>
> *Figure 5.4.2: Collector current increase with an increase of the collector-emitter voltage due to the Early effect. The Early voltage, V<sub>A</sub>, is also indicated on the figure.*

**This variation can be expressed by the Early voltage, VA, which quantifies what voltage variation would result in zero collector current.**

> [image]

Because Ib is constant, the common emitter DC current gain (beta) increases proportionally with the collector current.
beta = Ic/Ib

Now, beta changes due to change in alpha :-

If alpha were truly constant, then Ic would be independent of V(CE) and curves would be horizontal. Because of Early Effect, alpha increases by 0.1 percent as V(CE) increases by 10 volts (say). Hence beta also increases.
beta changes as follows :

[image]

[image: \beta_\mathrm{F0}] is forward common-emitter current gain at zero bias.

***Due to change in beta, Ic changes even though Ib remains constant.***

> In addition to the Early effect, there is a less pronounced effect due to the variation of the base-emitter voltage, which changes the ideality factor of the collector current. However, the effect at the base-emitter junction is much smaller since the base-emitter junction capacitance is larger and the base-emitter voltage variation is very limited since the junction is forward biased. This effect does lead to a variation of the ideality factor, n
>
> [image]

I hope this will help.

[https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter5/ch5_4.htm](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Ebart/book/book/chapter5/ch5_4.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I agree that keeping \$V_{be}\$ constant and then varying \$V_{ce}\$ would be similar to keeping \$I_b\$ constant and varying \$V_{ce}\$. The goal is to set a certain \$I_c\$, then vary \$V_{ce}\$ and look at the changes in \$I_c\$.

I would prefer setting \$I_b\$, as 
$$
I_c = \beta I_b
$$ 
is valid over a huge current range. \$I_c\$ as a function of \$V_{be}\$ is much more dependent on temperature and physical properties.

Q2: By calculating the small signal parameter \$r_o\$ (\$\frac{dV_{ce}}{dI_c}\$) for both cases (constant \$I_b\$ or \$V_{be}\$).

Comment: Yes - regarding Q2 I had the same idea. Here is the result (to befound elsewhere):y22=h22 - h12*h21/h11=h22 - h12*gm. From this I derive, that y22=h22 is valid only if the second part can be neglected. But numeric examples show that it must NOT be neglected. Therefore my question.

Comment: When you fill in the numerics, be aware of large signal properties (like Ib, Vbe, Ic) and small signal properties (like gm, r0) and don't mix them up (common beginner's mistake ;-) )

Comment: Nice, I just type and someone else does the formatting for me, thanks Greg :-)

Comment: Rimpelbekkie, I speak about small-signal operation only because the Early voltage is definded for small signals.

Comment: Rimpelbekkie, regarding your answer to Q1 I am not sure about your point of view (..."similar to keeping Ib constant"). I do not speak about a designers "goal" but my question rather concerns a DEFINITION. Do you understand what I mean?